# calling php function from jquery ajax with include statement error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, include

I have a problem with my include statements. I have several php files that are loaded when the page is initially loaded and then called again by jQuery ajax calls. Because of the ajax calls I don't have the php script in a function and but I am getting an error with my includes statement when I call them from a different location (the ajax call). For example my main page includes this php script:

```
<div id="controlPanelForm">
    <?php include "lib/getControlPanel.php"; ?>
</div>
```

Here is the first few lines of the getControlPanel.php file:

```
<?php
include_once("../etc/includes.php");
...do something...
```

Here is the ajax call:

```
    function getControl(teamID)
{     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: {teamID: teamID},
            url: "./lib/getControlPanel.php",
            dataType: "html",
            async: true,
            success: function(response) 
            {
                $('#controlPanelForm').html(response);
            }
    });
}
```

So the problem is when I call the php script from the ajax call I get this error:

```
include_once(../etc/includes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

If I change the relative path, the original include from the main page doesn't work...

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably need the file to be an absolute path. It's trying to include that file from wherever your jQuery file is being run.

Comment: I tried that but in my includes.php file I define a function and I get an error stating that I cannot re-declare a function.

Comment: Your file is being referenced incorrectly. Try hitting getControlPanel.php in your browser and you will get the same error.
As a note, Kacey: it is not referencing the file relative to the file making the ajax call. The path is relative to the file that makes the include/require call.

Comment: That's what I was getting at. That's why I said change it to an absolute path, that way where ever it's called from it will load the file.

Comment: When I do an absolute path the initial include of the file from the main page works, but since I am using `include_once` the next time it is called from the ajax call it does not load. If I just do `include` I get this error on the initial include from the main page: `CONSTANT HOST ALREADY DEFINED`...

Comment: That error indicates that you are including the file multiple times (and consequently defining your classes/methods multiple times). Make sure you don't have multiple include/require statements referencing includes.php in your getControlPanel.php file.

Comment: I have one more suggestion for you, unrelated to the problem. You say you don't have the code in functions because you later call it by AJAX. Can you include a "?ajax=true" parameter or something like that? That way you can check on the include: if there is the "ajax" param, you execute your function, and if no param, you don't (the code later on will). Feasible?

Comment: Or it could be that you define something in includes.php that is also defined in getControlPanel.php. We could better help you troubleshoot that particular problem if you provided the contents of both files.

Comment: You wouldn't need an ajax get parameter. You can test if a request is ajax using the function `function is_ajax()
{
  return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND 
          strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest');
}`

Answer (score 3):

```
include_once(../etc/includes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

This error indicates that the file at '../etc/includes.php' doesn't exist. You can see your current working directory using [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) to determine where your relative links are actually pointing.

Relative paths, however, are a pain. I never use them. All of my projects contain a config.php file containing the configuration values:

```
// paths and urls
define('SITE_PATH', '/var/www/my_website/');
define('SITE_URL', 'http://localhost/my_website/');
```

Now everything can be absolute. Modifying your example:

```
<div id="controlPanelForm">
    <?php include SITE_PATH . 'lib/getControlPanel.php'; ?>
</div>
```

getControlPanel.php:

```
<?php
include_once(SITE_PATH . 'etc/includes.php');
```

Lots more can be done with these defines such as creating functions for loading files, sending redirect headers, etc.

On a side note, always test the ajax page by going to it directly using a web browser prior to debugging it with the AJAX call. That way you can tell whether the problem is a php problem or a javascript problem.

Comment: Then wouldn't I run into the same issue with including the config.php file?

Comment: The config.php file is the only file you would need to know how to include. The rest you can be sure will be included using the correct path.

Comment: Use `getcwd()` to see your working directory. Then `include 'config.php';` with the path from your working directory to your config.php.

Comment: If your still stuck read about [includes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [paths](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm), and [configuration files](http://eeinsider.com/articles/creating-a-robust-config.php-file/)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by correcting the path to your included file (includes.php). You can reference it asbolute or relative, doesn't matter. The important thing is that it is properly referenced.

Having said that, I prefer absolute paths (using constants to define paths up to web/app root).

To figure out the proper path (whether you want to use relative or absolute), drop a

```
echo phpinfo();
```

in your file and take a look at the DOCUMENT_ROOT or SCRIPT_FILENAME vars.